# ¿Cómo traducirían al inglés "Universidad Nacional de General Sarmiento"?

Tags: traducción

No creo que sería `General Sarmiento National University` porque la universidad no está en General Sarmiento (se dividió hace años y se formaron distintos distritos). `National University of General Sarmiento` me suena raro, me incomoda.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola. No entiendo el fundamento de que como no está en General Sarmiento no se puede llamar "General Sarmiento National University". Me parece que es la forma más correcta. Tomo como ejemplos la Universidad de Harvard (Harvard University) y la Universidad de Columbia (Columbia University); la primera está en Cambridge y la segunda en Manhattan. Actualmente no tienen relación con el lugar donde están asentadas.

Comment: De todos modos, nótese que este sitio debate sobre el castellano y en este caso buscas una traducción al inglés. ¿No sería más práctico preguntarlo en [ell.se] o [english.se]?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is about a translation to English, not about Spanish language.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes razón.

> National University of General Sarmiento

...sería lo mejor dicho.

Pero también se podría referirla como pusiste.

> General Sarmiento National University.

Pues, ambos dichos son buenos.